# variable type change from global variable to method variable why?

Tags: python, methods, global-variables

I initate a variable globally then when I go to change the variable it's type goes from dictionary (good) to string ( bad) and I am kinda sure why but not really. I am not 100% on python scoping.

The code in full is below please notice I have alot of print statements which I was using as testing. I am including all the code to the point of the issue to give you all a full grasp of what  I am trying to do.

```
totalEntries = 0
print 'this is first ' + str((type(totalEntries))) #prints type int (good)
perPage = 0
currentPage = 1
Pcity = ''

api_data = ''
is_last_page = False
apiCallNum = 1
tableDefined = False


def getApiData(city):
    global Pcity
    global apiCallNum
    global apiEndpoint
    Pcity = city
    apiEndpoint = #just a link ignore this

    api_data = requests.get(apiEndpoint).json()
    print(api_data)
    print('your testing this' + str(type(api_data))) #prints dict (good)

    print ("Current API Call " + str(apiCallNum))

    apiCallNum += 1



    print('your testing this' + str(type(api_data))) #prints dict (good)


def populateVars():
    global totalEntries

    print "this is second " + str(type(totalEntries)) #prints int (good)

    print('your testing this' + str(type(api_data))) #prints string (bad)
    totalEntries = api_data['total_entries']
```

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments made to `api_data` inside `getApiData` won't be visible anywhere else because you didn't mark it as global.

Add `global api_data` to the beginning of `getApiData`.

Incidentally, you only need the global statement if you want to assign to a global variable - you can access their values just fine without the statement. So strictly speaking you don't need `global apiEndpoint`.

Comment: thank you Kevin. Additionally What I did after relaxing for a moment was initalize api_data as a empty dictionary. When I tested the type the last type test came out as a dicitonary. I now have a new issue which is showing as    totalEntries = api_data['total_entries']
KeyError: 'total_entries'

Comment: i'm going to try and figure out why that is, otherwise I will update this question. Kevin thank you for your helps

Comment: @ChristopherJakob If you've got a new question - the best plan / way you're supposed to do it is to mark this one as solved and open a new one with the new issue.